# "The day someone does something" or "the day someone will do something"?

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

Tell me please if I need to use the helping verb *will* when referring to the future in the following context.

> The day I (**will**) get my diploma, I will celebrate it with all my friends.

Comment: If you don't want to, you don't need to use *will* at all: *The day I get my diploma is the day I celebrate with all my friends.* (I could come up with other ways of writing it too.)

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to use *will* two times.

> The day I get my diploma, I will celebrate it with all my friends.

This is fine since you have *will* in "I will celebrate".